# How to see a certificate keysize using keytool?

Tags: java, keytool

When the certificate is created it is possible to configure `-keysize` option for command `genkeypair`.

Is it possible to see a certificate keysize using keytool?

I have tried these options without success:

```
keytool  -list –rfc

keytool  -list –v
```

Was not able to find it here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_list

Comment: "size"? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible with keytool, but there is a GUI alternative called "[KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/)" that shows the key size:

[image: KeyStore Explorer]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if I run the following command I will see the bit size listed under my Alias

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {name of keystore}
```

The following are lines I see on my private certificate (non-root cert)

> Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key